# UITableView's scrollToRowAtIndexPath does not work when the cell is not showing?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

This is a bit more unique than the title describes.

I have 28 cells being displayed dynamically on a UITableView. I chose to do this dynamically because there are so many, but I always know there will be a fixed number of rows, that I know upon loading.

Each cell has a UITextField on it.

When the user is on the UITextField in row 0, for example, and they press 'Return' on the keyboard, it 'tabs' the to UITextField in row 1. Later-rinse-repeat for row 2, row 3, and so forth. This works just fine. However, it does not work if the row currently being edited by the user is scrolled offscreen. So for example, if the user is editing the UITextField in row 0, then scrolls the UITableView down to show visibly show rows 10-22 as an arbitrary example, and then pressed 'Return' on the keyboard, the view is scrolled all the way back up, but UITextField in row 1 has not becomeFirstResponder, and the keyboard has disappeared.

Is this because it takes time to animate the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` code? Why is this currently not working, and how can I make it work so that the next UITextField in sequence will becomeFirstResponder when the UITableView has been scrolled away?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    CGPoint textFieldOriginInTableView = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:textFieldOriginInTableView];

    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn: %zd", indexPath.row);

    if (indexPath.row < (self.categories.count - 1)) {
        NSIndexPath *nextIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row+1) inSection:0];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nextIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
        MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndex];
        [cell.categoryValue becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [self doneTapped:self];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention in the OP above that the indexPath retrieved currently is always correct. No matter where I am scrolled in the UITableView, the NSLog statement in the code above always returns the correct IndexPath.row.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would try to keep track of the nextIndexPath (property or ivar) and then implement the -[tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] method of UITableViewDelegate protocol, so you can check the correct visible cell.

Another solution is blocking the user interaction over the tableView when a textField becomes first responder. Or resign the first responder when the tableView is scrolled. It is a simpler solution and has a better UX in my opinion.